# Workarounds for IE9 (early) support

Tags: asp.net, html, browser, meta-tags

Some users on my site are now on the IE9 betas. It works very poorly with our app, especially as our site uses Telerik ASP.NET AJAX controls, which don't yet have IE9 support.

Is there ANY problem to use the following tag as a quick hack to make our app continue to function, even as IE9 users start to drift in:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" >
```

More importantly, is there any chance the above tag can break functionality for our existing IE7, IE8, Chrome or Firefox users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it will not at all, it merely tells Internet Explorer to render using the specified engine, if it supports that engine (for example IE 7 cannot render in IE 8 mode). This diagram is useful to see how the process works: http://ieblog.members.winisp.net/misc/How%20IE9%20Determines%20Document%20Mode.svg

Comment: Yep, it should be fine. It will change the [document standards mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565624(VS.85).aspx) to IE8 standards.